# Why does std::sort crash when working with a QList?

Tags: c++, qt

I get a couple different crashes running the below code, sometimes a segmentation fault and sometimes `ASSERT: "&other != this" in file C:/Qt/5.12.3/mingw73_64/include/QtCore/qstring.h, line 958`.

The code to reproduce this is below.

```
#include <QList>
#include <QDebug>

class Tag
{
public:
    Tag(const QString& name)
    {
        this->name = new QString(name);
    }

    Tag(const Tag& tag)
    {
        this->name = new QString(tag.getName());
    }

    ~Tag()
    {
        if (name != nullptr) delete name;
    }

    QString getName() const
    {
        return *name;
    }

    static bool sortByName(const Tag& t1, const Tag& t2)
    {
        return t1.getName() < t2.getName();
    }

private:
    QString* name;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QList<Tag> tags;

    Tag a("a");
    Tag b("b");
    Tag c("c");
    Tag d("d");
    Tag e("e");

    tags << e << c << a << b << d;

    qDebug() << "before sorting";
    for (Tag tag : tags) {
        qDebug() << tag.getName();
    }

    std::sort(tags.begin(), tags.end(), Tag::sortByName);

    qDebug() << "after sorting";
    for (Tag tag : tags) {
        qDebug() << tag.getName();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have noticed that if the initial `QList` is filled with pointers to `Tag` objects and `sortByName()` is changed to accept pointers instead, it does not cause issues. I'm at a loss as to why.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/

Comment: What rafix07 is trying to say is that your `Tag` class has a rule of 3/5/0 violation.

Comment: Off-topic: it's legal to delete a null pointer, so you don't need to check in destructor... Any reason for not aggregating the string directly (`private: QString name;`)? That would make your life much easier...

Comment: Thank you all for the help! rafix07's suggestion solved my issue, and I will give the stack overflow thread linked by Nemo a read, thanks again.

Comment: @Aconcagua I may have been falsely taught that you should use pointers wherever possible as otherwise you may get a stack (or was it heap?) overflow. Is there no benefit to doing so?

Comment: Well, it depends... If you have large arrays of objects, or if you have really huge objects, stack overflow *can* occur. But QString itself is a rather small object, that won't hurt on the stack (data is maintained internally on the heap anyway). Additionally: The QString is embedded in the Tag class anyway, you still can decide having the `Tag` on stack or heap (together with the embedded string) just as you like...

Comment: @Aconcagua Thank you for the help, I'm glad the problem here was solved, but I do believe you are right and the best thing would be to make the QString not a pointer.

Comment: By the way: In embedded environments, you usually avoid dynamic allocation completely, as there are other dangers it can bring with it (memory fragmentation, for instance).

Comment: Yeah, `QString` shouldn't be a pointer like... ever. It uses copy-on-write sematics anyway and stores the text in heap, so using `new` on it is basically double overhead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root of the problem is that you are using a raw pointer as a member variable (name) and trying to explicitly do a manual allocation/copy without the rule of 3 being satisfied.  `sort` is invoking the copy assignment operator and getting the default implementation - which is to blindly copy the pointer value.  Hence, double delete and crash...

The simplest fix is to just change `name` from a pointer to a concrete instance.

That is, this compiles and works fine with the `main` you already have provided.

```
class Tag
{
public:
    Tag(const QString& name) : _name(name)
    {
    }

    const QString& getName() const
    {
        return _name;
    }

    static bool sortByName(const Tag& t1, const Tag& t2)
    {
        return t1.getName() < t2.getName();
    }

private:
    QString _name;
};
```

If you actually need to keep `name` as a pointer, then add a copy assignment operator method to your Tag class:

```
class Tag
{
    …

    Tag& operator=(const Tag& t)
    {
        Qstring* oldName = this->name;
        this->name = new QString(t.getName());
        delete oldName;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: Uh, oh – what, if `this` already contained another string (`operator=`)?

Comment: Would `this->name = new QString(t.getName());` result in a memory leak?

Comment: Good callout. Fixed.  And yes, I deleted the pointer after overwriting assignment in case of self-assignment.

Comment: @Corvus Important (that's done correctly here): *Always* create the new object first *before* you delete the old one; this way you're object remains in a valid state in case of an exception occurring on construction (e. g. `std::bad_alloc`).